# Can I upload a file in public folder aside a Laravel installation?

Tags: laravel, file-upload, hosting

I can't retrieve files from a public folder in my hosting because I have a laravel installation, I only want to keep files that I could retrieve from an url like this: domain.com/folder/file01.pdf but every time I try to access it throws an ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS where can I upload them or what do I need to do in order to access this files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you certain you server is configured correctly?

You should be able to access any file or folder you put in the laravel `public` folder without any issues.

So for instance if you put a image into `public/images/image.jpg` you should be able to access it from `www.domain.com/images/image.jpg`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was trying to access an index.html file just by calling the folder (ex. domain.com/public/folder/), expecting it to work as it normally does, but with laravel it is imperative to call the exact file you want to access so I had to call it as domain.com/public/folder/index.html

Sorry if it is a dumb mistake, thanks for your help.